# R - y axis limit/range for hexbin plot

Tags: r, math, graph, range

I am attempting limit the range of a saved plot in R. I am able to do so in a normal plot like so without any set range:

```
library(hexbin)
library(lattice)

data <- read.table("textfile.txt", as.is=TRUE);

xpts <- data[,1];
ypts <- data[,2];

jpeg('plot.jpg', width = 1000, height = 1000);
plot(xpts, ypts);
dev.off();
```

I then get the following image:

[image]

I then set my own y-axis limit from 0 to 10 using ylim in the plot function:

```
library(hexbin)
library(lattice)

data <- read.table("textfile.txt", as.is=TRUE);

xpts <- data[,1];
ypts <- data[,2];

jpeg('plot.jpg', width = 1000, height = 1000);
plot(xpts, ypts, ylim=c(0,10));
dev.off();
```

I then get the following image:

[image]

I have to make a hexbin plot. It works great without a range limit, like so:

```
library(hexbin)
library(lattice)

data <- read.table("textfile.txt", as.is=TRUE);

xpts <- data[,1];
ypts <- data[,2];

bin <- hexbin(x=xpts, y=ypts);

jpeg('hexplot.jpg', width = 1000, height = 1000);
plot(bin);
dev.off();
```

and I get the following image:

[image]

Then, when I try to set a similar ylim on the hexbin, I get errors. I've tried ybnds as it's something that others have tried, but I don't know how to set the range. I have something like this:

```
library(hexbin)
library(lattice)

data <- read.table("textfile.txt", as.is=TRUE);

xpts <- data[,1];
ypts <- data[,2];

bin <- hexbin(x=xpts, y=ypts, ybnds=c(0,10));

jpeg('hexplot.jpg', width = 1000, height = 1000);
plot(bin);
dev.off();
```

I get the following error:

Error in hexbin(x = xpts, y = ypts, ybnds = c(0, 10)) : 
  'ybnds' must encompass range(y)
Execution halted

I have also tried ylim, but it seems I can't use it for hexbin. It would be great if someone would help me out - truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try restricting the data input:

```
data <- read.table("textfile.txt", as.is=TRUE);

xpts <- data[,1][ data[,2] <= 10 & data[,2]>=0] 
ypts <- data[,2][ data[,2] <= 10 & data[,2]>=0]
```

(You don't need terminating semi-colons at the end of lines.)

Comment: Thank you! And the semicolons are just a habit.